# Disruptor Pattern with fixed size byte array message

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I want to take advantage of the preallocated memory paradigm inside the LMAX Disruptor package and my entries are fixed size messages.. (say byte array or something)..

How do you define the entry class? (ie the 'ValueEvent' in order to get a fixed size byte array? ) In Java, won't you only declare the reference to the array? How do you define a fixed size byte array as member variable in a class? Thanks!

Comment: How did you define the entry class (show some of the code) and what problems are having with it?

Comment: I'm going through the examples in the Disruptor package and I found this

`public final static EventFactory<ByteBuffer> EVENT_FACTORY = new EventFactory<ByteBuffer>()
    {
        public ByteBuffer newInstance()
        {
            return ByteBuffer.allocate(m_size);
        }
    }; `

In this particular case, the ByteBuffer lives somewhere on heap where each one of the ByteBuffer entry is not next the each other, correct? (Only the references are next to each other)